# Is it possible to sync clips in Adobe Premiere Pro when there are more than one clip per track?

Tags: premiere

I have the recordings from 4 cameras. The recordings were broken into smaller files, something the cameras do by themselves, but the cameras were also turned on and off. I don't know when the boundaries between two consecutive clips is the automatic file cut or a camera on/off.

I want to do a pass watching all the footage on all the angles in multicam mode, to learn what's on each camera and start editing this. The problem that I'm having is that Adobe Premiere Pro doesn't seem to be able to synchronize clips when I select more than one clip per track.

This might help. I'm trying to synchronize this:

[image]

and yes, there might be gaps, when a camera was turned off for a bit and turned back on again. That's ok.

I can only synchronize this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the answer is no, which means syncing each column of clips by hand.

I understand Premiere Pro wants to avoid one clip conflicting with another, but that's trivial to detect and they could just abort syncing those when that happens. They already avoid synchronizing when the audio doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Sync by making a multicam source sequence from the clips in your bin.  You’ll have to rearrange the clips in the timeline since it will send them to different tracks but it will sync all of them